# What is the minimum screen size I need to cater for on a website

Tags: html, css, screen

What do people think is the minimum screen size one needs to cater for? 
640px?

Is there are hard and fast rule like the old 960px wide?

Thanks

Comment: 320px. That's the smallest mobile device screen. Best test of responsive design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question like;

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842638/whats-the-standard-minimum-resolution-i-should-support-with-a-website

http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/which-minimum-browser-or-screen-resolution-should-i-target-my-web-apps
```

Min. resolution for responsive layout that should be supported is `320px X 480px` i.e. iPhone resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah totally true what has already been said that the minimum screen size you have to cater to is usually 320px.

Also, I would say that after you deploy the site, you should monitor it frequently with Google Analytics which will tell you what screen-size your website visitors are using.

Answer (score 0):

Today we have a lot of screen sizes. I don't think we have a minimum sreen size. And if we have, probably it will be the iWatch...
http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bb/d1/a2/bbd1a29bf07aa047ac66a74f88751328.jpg

Comment: That looks pretty high-res to me.