# Liquid layout versus fixed layout : which one to chose?

Tags: css, layout, liquid-layout

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456250/recommended-website-resolution-width-and-height), it is said in the most upvoted answer:

> Use liquid layouts

Why this is considered a good practice ? My opinion is that it is more difficult to dezign a liquid layouts because it can vary quite a bit from one window size to another... Is the extra complexity worth it ? What i should take into account to make the choice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, I disagree with that. With a fixed-width layout you can create something which will be viewed the same on all browsers.

I've been in web design and development for quite a while now and there have been very few times I've ever used liquid layouts on a website.

There are some times when it can come in useful, web apps sometimes can benefit from having a liquid layout. However, the safest (in terms of design and everything working across different browsers, screens etc), best looking (in my opinion) and "standard" way to create websites is with a fixed width.

Just look around. See the websites which have a liquid layout and ask yourself why they have a liquid layout. Do they have a lot of areas of dynamic/varying text for instance? Lots of information to show? Lack of visual/graphical design? Its a very subjective area, but one which you'll have to choose between. Does your website look better fixed or liquid? Do you want people with huge monitors (like me - 27" imac) to have to see your website really fat? I hate viewing amazon on my mac!

Comment: mail.google.com, news.google.fr, www.google.com, amazon.com, wikipedia.com... They are quite a few

Comment: -1 Not only most websites have fixed layouts, but have also sloppy UI, with terrifying old spaghetti code mash-up. The truth is that those websites are OLD and should be rewritten entirely from scratch.

Comment: @pinouchon I would call mail.google.com a web app, dunno about the news website, google.com is fixed width, amazon.com looks atrocious imo. Wikipedia has a lot of content textual content and therefore falls under "times when it can be useful". So out of your list there are 2 that are 'viable' for your argument, even then its only a list of 5.

Comment: @jose that wasn't the question. the question was which one he should choose. My answer was largely objective based on personal experience (as noted in the answer). No need to -1.

Comment: @Thomas: You're right, sorry for that. What I didn't like was "Just look around, how many websites nowadays have a liquid layout?". Seems like nobody uses a liquid layout cause it's somewhat a bad thing, or that if nobody uses it then it means it's not good, but of course your answer state otherwise. If you edit something I will be able to give back the vote.

Comment: @jose - fair enough. I've edited the quote you pointed out to clarify and maybe give a bit more advice to the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I find liquid layouts are always harder to work with, but they look nicer when it is nicely designed.

You can take a look at some grid css frameworks that can help you working with liquid layout.

- http://www.designbyfire.com/liquid_blueprint/tests/liquid.html blueprint liquid
- http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/ Fluid 960 Grid System

Answer (score 1):

The right choice depend on what are your needs.

Liquid layouts are perhaps more difficult to understand and implement, but you gain **flexibility**.

A flexibile layout means it can easily **adapt** to different screen resolutions.

Once you have your liquid layout done, you can possibly adapt it also for mobile websites (if it isn't already) with a couple of changes, mainly CSS rules.

With the fast pace at which new technologies come out (new devices, new screens, new resolutions, 16:9, 16:10, Full HD etc), you can easily implement a layout which has no problem displaying at various resolutions on different displays.

This is what liquid layouts are for.

On the other hand, a static website is nothing more than what we've seen in the past years, like a centered 960px wide page, unable to being displayed on most mobiles, and even if they display it, good luck navigating the website.

Note that you can actually implement a sort of hybrid: a fixed size layout, with a max width of let's say 960px to be viewable in desktop browsers normally, which then adapt to lower resolution with an auto width.